# Converting ArrayList of enums to String

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist, enums

I have the following `enum`s, which can fill an `ArrayList`:

```
public enum RewardType {
    POINTS, MONEY, TOKENS, RANDOM;
}
```

and

```
public enum OfferType {
    GIFT, DISCOUNT, LOTTERY;
}
```

To convert the `ArrayList` to `String` I use this method:

```
public static String arrayListToString(ArrayList<Enum> arrayList) {
    String finalString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(finalString)) {
            finalString = arrayList.get(i).name();
        } else {
            finalString = finalString + ", " + arrayList.get(i).name();
        }
    }
    return finalString;
}
```

and then I call it like this:

```
String rewardType = arrayListToString(mainModel.getRewardTypes()); 
//getRewardTypes returns an ArrayList<RewardType>
```

The problem is, that `arrayListToString` is called with `ArrayList<Enum>` and cannot be called with `ArrayList<enum>` parameter (which is the type of my classes). I also cannot create a class with type `Enum`. Since `enum` != `Enum`, how do I make `arrayListToString` method work with my `enum` classes?

Comment: Note that enum values are effectively constants, and according to the Java Naming Conventions, they should be written in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE. Also, you can leave out those empty constructors, since they're automatically created when you specify no other constructor.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that about the empty constructors. I am familiar with the naming conventions of Java, it's just that in my case, my server will expect Pascal Cased parameters. That's why the enums are named like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since an `enum X` is implicitly a subclass of `Enum<X>`, change method declaration to:

```
public static String arrayListToString(ArrayList<? extends Enum> arrayList)
```

However, why do that?

The `toString()` of a enum returns the `name()` by default, so you don't need to call `name()`, which means you don't really care what's in the list anymore, so this much more generally useful method will work too:

```
public static String listToString(List<?> list) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (Object value : list) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            buf.append(", ");
        buf.append(value);
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

It can be even simpler than that:

```
public static String toString(Iterable<?> iterable) {
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
    for (Object value : iterable)
        joiner.add(String.valueOf(value));
    return joiner.toString();
}
```

Or with Java 8+ streams:

```
public static String toString(Collection<?> coll) {
    return coll.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the signature of `arrayListToString()` from this:

> ```
> public static String arrayListToString(ArrayList<Enum> arrayList)
> ```

to this:

```
public static String arrayListToString(ArrayList<? extends Enum> arrayList)
```

---

The core concept at play is that a `List<Integer>` is **not** a `List<Number>`, even though an `Integer` is a `Number`. This makes sense, because you could put a `Double` into a `List<Number>` but you could not put a `Double` into a `List<Integer>`.

Similarly, a `List<RewardType>` is not a `List<Enum>`, even though a `RewardType` is an `Enum`.

A `List<RewardType>` **is**, though, a `List<? extends Enum>`. This is because we now are saying that the list is a list of *some sort of enum*, not a list of *any enum ever*.

Comment: Ben P. Better to use `List< ? extends Enum<?> > arrayList` since `Enum` is parametrized type.

Comment: I think if we want to be super technical, the best representation would be `public static <E extends Enum<E>> String arrayListToString(ArrayList<E> arrayList)`, but I wanted to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Ben, You should use type generics to properly evaluate the type.

Aside from that, your method is slightly unoptimized. Consider using `StringBuilder` to prevent creation of garbage `String` objects, and remove redundant `isEmpty` check inside your loop:

```
public static <T extends Enum<?>> String enumListToString(List<T> list){
    if(list.size() < 1)
        return "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(list.get(0).name());
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        sb.append(", ").append(list.get(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: `<T extends Enum<T>>`